# Transfer Contacts from Blackberry to I-phone in blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, contacts

I am working on a Default phonebook contacts application, In my app i m trying to transfer my BB contacts to Iphone device. Currently doing R & D on this task.
Please let me know, as blackberry is known for its security, after that, is this task possible?
Thanxx i advance.

Comment: Do you know how to convert the contacts to IPhone? because we know how to get the contact lists from blackberry;

Comment: Thats the only problem, how can i transfer the contacts from Blackberry to I phone. And the rest task, to get the contact list, i had done with that in my last application.

Comment: Acutally, I used to have the same problem and i solved it with a method. and i post it for you to [transfer your contacts from BB to iPhone](http://www.transfer-iphone-recovery.com/blackberry-contacts-to-iphone.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to transfer contacts between different mobile devices. This way does not involve programming skills and does not need any special custom software installed.

1. Connect your blackberry to your computer and synchronize contacts with your mail client, let say Outlook.
2. Disconnect blackberry, and connect iPhone to your computer and synchronize contacts with Outlook again.

That's it.

There is no way to transfer contacts directly using *your application* unless you have documentation on the formats and synchronization protocols for both of the platforms.